# How to verify SCP transfer was successful?

Tags: ssh, php, scp

I'm using http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ to make an SSH connection to my server, then execute an SCP command to transfers to a remote server. The library's `exec()` method returns a string (looks like the standard output of the SCP command) instead of the return value of the command (e.g. `0` to indicate success).

I'm reluctant to do some sort of string comparison to determine if the SCP transfer was successful or not (right now, I get "stdin: is not a tty"). Is there an SSH command I can use to determine if a file exist on another server? Or any suggestions on how else I can verify if the file transferred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enablyPTY()` should fix the stdin: is not a tty. You can also suppress stderr in phpseclib with `enableQuietMode()`. `getExitStatus()` will return the exit status.